# http download all files that start with a string

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I need to download n # of files from an http location using `urllib2` which start with a given pattern `"my_file_$TIMESTAMP.xml"`.  I'd like to get all files that start with `"my_file"` excluding the timestamp component.

I've seen how this is possible using `glob` for local files here: [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-with-python) but i'm not sure if this is possible over an http connection with basic authentication?

Comment: Is this HTTP or FTP? They're different protocols.

Comment: Without some kind of sitemap or directory index, this is pretty much impossible. (Short of brute force requesting the huge number of possibilities.)

Comment: @Wooble that is *not* what i want to hear :)

Comment: If you don't have a directory listing but you know the files are there, maybe you could follow the same procedure you use to determine which files are there, with a scraping library?

Comment: if you know what the min/max timestamps are ... just set up a cloud to step through all timestamps between (Im assuming numeric timestamps) It shouldnt take it more than a few hours probably

Comment: @JoranBeasley that won't work for me because these operations will need to be performed and repeated in the order of seconds.

Comment: do you have any control over the server?

Comment: @JoranBeasley unfortunately no.  its a 3rd party's

Comment: if you just goto http://url.com/folder_with_xmls/ do you see a listing of them? if so you can just scrape that with requests(or urllib). where are you trying to scrape these from?